# Closing child popup window fails in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I have a problem closing a child popup window. When I click on the link on the parent window, a new child window opens (this window is used to launch the right software using the URL). My goal is to get this child window closed as soon as it launches the required tool, leaving the parent window open.

This is my code:

```
<a href="<s:property value="URL" />" rel="notes" target="_self">
```

The JQuery :

```
$recherche_globale_a_rel.filter('[rel="notes"]').click(function () {
    var myPage = window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    myPage.close();
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that the child window closes properly when using firefox, but doesn't close when I use IE (IE8). 
Any help??

Comment: What you have should work fine in IE8. Try looking in the console in case any errors have been raised which are stopping execution

Comment: I have looked at the console to see if there are any errors, absolutly nothing! Everything looks fine :(

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have problem here:

```
<a href="<s:property value="URL" />" rel="notes" target="_self">
```

Since you have doble quotes inside double quotes, try changing it:

```
<a href="<s:property value='URL' />" rel="notes" target="_self"></a>
```

or:

```
<a href="<s:property value=\"URL\" />" rel="notes" target="_self"></a>
```

Comment: I just tried that.  unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @user1353307 Were you able to find any solution ?Facing the same issue